# Displaying JSON data on a textView in a correct format

Tags: java, android, json

> Hello, would anyone help me display this type of JSON array on a textView in the correct way. Any response will be highly appreciated!

```
{"result":[{"drugbrand":"Bactiflox","manu":"Mepha","details":"Tabs, 250 mg (10 s = Ke: 780.00), 500mg (10 s = Ke: 1,025.00), 750 mg (10 s = Ke: 1,345.00)"}]}
```

> Am using the belo code but its giving out an exception: org.json.JSONException: Value ﻿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

```
try {
            JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                String name = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("drugbrand");
                String manufacturer = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("manu");
                String info = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("details");
                jsonText = name + "\n" + manufacturer + "\n" + info;

                outputText.setText(jsonText);

            }


        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: result is JSONObject not a JSONArray

Comment: Does it mean that where I wrote JSONArray on the try block above should be overwritten by JSONObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response It's a `JSONObject`:

```
{"result":[{"drugbrand":"Bactiflox","manu":"Mepha","details":"Tabs, 250 mg (10 s = Ke: 780.00), 500mg (10 s = Ke: 1,025.00), 750 mg (10 s = Ke: 1,345.00)"}]}
```

You only need to create this `JSONObject` and them get the `JSONArray` :

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray jArray= jObj.getJSONArray("result");
```

The `JSONArray` is inside the `JSONObject` with the tag "result"